# Get the bounding box of a selected SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-edit

I want to read:

- `width`,`height`,`x`,`y` measurements

for a particular SVG element.

---

I suppose that easiest way to go about this is to fetch the [*minimum bounding box*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) first and read it's properties.

How can I access this?

Comment: It would be helpful to say in the question above that you're using svg-edit: http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a handle to the element, I would think that this would work, no?

```
box = svgedit.utilities.getBBox(selected);
```

Comment: @niteshsingh My question is tagged with `svg-edit`, an online SVG editor hence this answer makes use of one of svg-edit's utility libraries.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a reference to the DOM node, use

```
svgNode.getBoundingClientRect()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect

Edit: SVG Edit has [a method](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svgcanvas.js#6200) to return currently selected elements:

```
svgCanvas.getSelectedElems()
```

so in the above example:

```
svgNode = svgCanvas.getSelectedElems()[0];
svgNode.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: thats what i use exactly. However i want to get the bounding box of a selected element. An element that has been selected on the canvas. I select the element then click a button that fires a function that gets its bounding box. I dont know what to substitute in the place of "svgNode" to get the value of a Selected element.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Please see http://granite.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/BBox0M.svg for the example and answer.

In brief, this code works for me in Chrome:

```
<script>
function foo(evt)
{
    console.log(evt.target.getBBox());      
}
</script>

<svg>
    <circle onclick="foo(evt)" r="20%" cx="50%" cy="50%"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but if you're looking to get the height or width of a jQuery element, use width() and height():

```
log("The svg is " + $("img").width() + "px wide.");
log("The svg is " + $("img").height() + "px tall.");
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gGWU4/

Comment: Actually i want to get the bounding box of an svg element that is clicked. The bounding box is a tightfitting box sourrounding the corners of any given svg element.

Comment: Would you be looking for code like this?
http://files.myopera.com/MacDev_ed/svg/coords/showbbox.js

From this page: http://files.myopera.com/MacDev_ed/svg/coords/sandbox.svg

Comment: This tells the height and the width, not the bounding box.