# Get bounding box of svg element?

Tags: svg, batik

I want to know the bounding box of an svg element. Taken from the project's examples:

```
DOMImplementation impl = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
String svgNS = SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI;
Document doc = impl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);
Element svgRoot = doc.getDocumentElement();

Element rectangle = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "10");
rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "20");
rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "100");
rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "50");
rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "red");

svgRoot.appendChild(rectangle);
```

Now I try finding the bounding box:

```
SVGOMElement svgelt = (SVGOMElement)rectangle;
SVGRect rc = SVGLocatableSupport.getBBox(svgelt); // rc == null
```

What's the right way to query an element's bounding box?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SVGLocatableSupport.getBBox(svgelt);`(instead of `(element)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the bounding box of a selected SVG element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926180/get-the-bounding-box-of-a-selected-svg-element)

Comment: @collapsar you're right, that was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is cobbled together from a few different sources:

```
Document doc = loadYerSvgDoc();
BridgeContext ctx = new BridgeContext(new UserAgentAdapter());
GraphicsNode gvtRoot = builder.build(ctx, doc);
Rectangle2D rc = gvtRoot.getSensitiveBounds();
```

that'll give you the bounds.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming the "builder" from above is an instance of GVTBuilder?